# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() php []

Tags: php, ajax, foreach, is-empty

I have this var `property` in UI part of and i do

`var property = JSON.stringify(valueToPush1);` it prints `[]`

so i know its empty i still send that value into php through ajax in my php i do

`$property = ($_POST['property']);
$jsonproperty = json_decode(stripslashes($property), true);`

I still check the property if empty so i do

`print_r($jsonproperty);`

and the ajax response is as expected empty like this `[]`

So what i did is to avoid the `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` i check if the variable is empty if empty i will not proceed. I do the checking like below.

```
if (!empty($jsonproperty)) {
    foreach($jsonproperty as $value) {}
}
```

But still i get the `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in` in line `foreach($jsonproperty as $value) {}`

1. How to check if the variable is empty in php especially if the `print_r` is `[]`

Comment: check $jsonproperty is an array or not using is_array function for more refer http://php.net/manual/fr/function.is-array.php

Comment: after checking?is it like if not array it is empty?

Comment: `$jsonproperty = json_decode('[]'); print_r($jsonproperty);` prints `Array()` and passing $jsonproperty to foreach doesn't raise a warning. Since you got `[]` as output (i.e. it's still a string containing a json-array) and the warning, there must be something wrong in your script, something you haven't shown us.

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`. It will tell you the type of `$jsonproperty`.

Comment: It's not an error to give an empty array to `foreach`. The error you got means that `$jsonproperty` is not an array at all.

Comment: @Barmar i see what you mean it prints `string(2) "[]"` How do you suggest i do it inorder to always get the array?even if the property from UI part is empty i still pass on a array on the php part?

Comment: @VolkerK this is how i add value into the property http://jsfiddle.net/q5bpc4pb/18/

Comment: You must be calling `JSON.stringify` twice on it. Show your code that performs the AJAX call.

Comment: thereit is i didnt see that one coming. i didnt check it. you are right @Barmar i stringify it here `var property = JSON.stringify(valueToPush1);` and here `formData.append('property', JSON.stringify(property));` you can post it as an answer ill be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `JSON.stringify` twice: once when you assign to `property`, and later when you append `property` to the `FormaData` parameter. Since you're only decoding it once in PHP, you get the string, not the array.

Just call `JSON.stringify` once when you're putting it into `formData`.